# Sorting data from one sheet to other sheets pulling only specific data

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need this done through app scripts

I need this sheet of data sorted and transferred to other sheets/workbooks: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y48N8W8CdaNlrxXopj5lnHTiNep33g_qA2-kTrPdt3A/edit#gid=130911536

If archive is no and Column E contains completed, I need put in the Sheet 'Projects to Archive' in the original workbook linked above

I need the data all the rows that don't contain 'completed' per unique name. This data gets put here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1brmAUrtF4Hu18X4bGYGekdEl8g4Sx1Eke5Q6KctJ4NU/edit#gid=0

Here are some examples of how I want my final sheets to look:
imgur.com/a/vQsWL6a

(colors are just for making it easier to explain, don't need to be in final solution)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Y48N8W8CdaNlrxXopj5lnHTiNep33g_qA2-kTrPdt3A", "Consolidated data!A:K"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col5,Col11 
  where Col1 = 'ACTIVE'
  and not Col5 = 'completed'")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will try this.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention. This needs to be done through app scripts because I people will be adding data to the sheet